# Accidentally run heroku pg:reset and my PG database has been deleted. Is it possible to rollback?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I run heroku repo:reset -a My_app_name

and system asked me: Warning: repo:reset is not a heroku command.Did you mean pg:reset? [y/n]:

I didn't notice that and answered Y.

There were several tables I really need. Is it possible to recreate at least they structure?

Comment: Do you have a [backup](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups)?

Comment: In any case, shouldn't your database structure be reflected in your source code (ideally defined by migrations)?

Comment: @Chris no, I don't

Comment: Agree, I can recreate structrure using code, but it is time consuming

Comment: How did you create the database tables etc. in the first place?

Comment: I created them in PG Admin.

Comment: I suggest you use [database migrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration) when you recreate them. Exactly how you do that will depend on the language, framework, etc. you are using. And then schedule [automatic backups](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups#scheduling-backups).